# MongoDb Debezium - "Connector config contains no connector type"

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to do a POC for Kafka and debezium.

I have started kafka and zookeeper and they are working... now when I try to load kafka-connect (I am kind of new to this...) I get this error that I just can't understand what I am doing wrong.

**Note: I have tested all of this with the Debezium tutorial docker images, but I would like to connect from a remote server and I thought it would be easier to install everything without docker to play with the configuration**

starting the connect with the following command

```
./connect-standalone.sh ~/kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties ~/kafka/config/connect-standalone-worker.properties ~/kafka/config/debezium-connector.properties
```

**connect-standalone.properties**

> ```
> bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
> key.converter.schemas.enable=true
> value.converter.schemas.enable=true
> offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
> plugin.path=/home/ubuntu/kafka/plugins
> ```

**connect-standalone-worker.properties**

> ```
> internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
> internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
> internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
> internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
> offset.storage.file.filename=/home/user/offest
> value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
> key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
> ```

**debezium-connector.properties**

> ```
> name=my-connector
> connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector
> include.schema.changes=false
> mongodb.name=mymongo
> collection.whitelist=my.collection
> tasks.max=1
> mongodb.hosts=A.B.C.D:27017
> ```

I get the following when running the connect:

> ```
> [2018-12-27 15:31:41,995] ERROR Failed to create job for /home/ubuntu/kafka/config/connect-standalone-worker.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:102)
> [2018-12-27 15:31:41,996] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:113)
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector config {internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter, offset.storage.file.filename=/home/user/offest, internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false, internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter, value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter, internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false, key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter} contains no connector type
>         at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:79)
>         at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:66)
>         at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:110)
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector config {internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter, offset.storage.file.filename=/home/user/offest, internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false, internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter, value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter, internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false, key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter} contains no connector type
>         at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:259)
>         at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:189)
>         at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:107)
> [2018-12-27 15:31:41,997] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:65)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`connect-standalone.properties` and `connect-standalone-worker.properties` need to be one file.

The error is saying that `connect-standalone-worker.properties` has no `connector.class` value (which it shouldn't because it's the worker properties, not a connector)

---

The command you're trying to run should look like

```
connect-standalone worker.properties connector1.properties [connector2.properties ... ]
```

Comment: AAAAAW!, god damn it!. thank you, my friend. may your cluster live forever.